# Excluding a list of a user's friends from the User.objects.all() queryset in django

Tags: python, django, list, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

In one of my views I override the get_queryset(self) method in order to return a list of users that excludes the friends of the user making the request and the same user. This is what my code looks like:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    all_users = User.objects.all()
    user_friends = Friend.objects.friends(self.request.user)
    # Filter all_users to exclude all elements of the user_friends queryset.
    # Filter all_users to exclude the current user making the request.
    # Return the filtered queryset.
```

I am using the [django-friendship](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship) library to handle friend requests and users being friends. In the [getting data about friendship section](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship#getting-data-about-friendships), it says to get a list of all a user's friends all that needs to be done is `Friend.objects.friends(request.user)`. I am unsure if this would return a list of Friend instances or of User instances. The source code for the Friend model is [here](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/blob/master/friendship/models.py). In either case, how would I filter the queryset `all_users` to exclude all elements of the list `user_friends`.

Comment: [`Friend`s](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/blob/ef711250a85b8d2d59af8bb7b61d088d3aea57e8/friendship/models.py#L343) have `to_user` and `from_user` attributes. When you say you want to filter the `all_users` `QuerySet`, should that be based on the `to_user` or the `from_user` values in `user_friends`?

Comment: It should be based on the attribute that gives that the user's friends. So isn't that to_user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the library enforces that friendships are reciprocal, so you should be able to exclude people who are friends of the user with just `User.objects.exclude(friends__from_user=self.request.user)`. Or `all_user.exclude(friends__from_user=self.request.user)` if you prefer.

To exclude the user as well, add a `.exclude(id=self.request.user.id)`. It doesn't matter whether that's before or after the friends exclude call.

`Friend.objects.friends(request.user)` returns a list of users, as you can see from inspecting its source:
https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/blob/ef711250a85b8d2d59af8bb7b61d088d3aea57e8/friendship/models.py#L154

The line `friends = [u.from_user for u in qs]` converts from a queryset of `Friend` instances into a list of users.

Comment: Does the User instance have a friends attribute? I implemented a custom user model.

Comment: By applying User.objects.exclude(friends=self.request.user) this will exclude all the user's friends and the same user too?

Comment: When I apply the change and call the view logged in as a test user with username: "regis@gmail.com", I get the following error: ValueError: Cannot query "regis@gmail.com": Must be "Friend" instance.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, updated to follow the FK relationship in the exclude.

Comment: Regardless of applying the latest suggested changes I still get an internal server error (julius@gmail.com is the current users username): ValueError: Cannot query "julius@gmail.com": Must be "Friend" instance.
[29/Jul/2017 06:06:25] "GET /users/search/?search=regis HTTP/1.1" 500 17711

Comment: That doesn't look like a standard Django exception, I'd look into how you're trying to resolve `request.user`. Searching by email isn't how the usual Django authentication framework works, so whatever you're using instead if what I'd look at.

Comment: Well, in my case the username is the email. In my User model.py I have USERNAME_FIELD = "email".

Comment: The examples are shown using an instance of the `User` model, not a username - if what you have is an email address, you want `User.objects.exclude(friends__from_user__email=some_email_address)` to exclude friends of the user with that address and `.exclude(email=some_email_address)` to exclude the user.

Comment: All I want is to filter the all_users query set such that the users friends and the same user are excluded. Even when I change the code to accomodate for the email address I still get an error. FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: from. It seems to refer to the line: User.objects.exclude(friends__from__user=self.request.user.email).

Comment: Use one `_` in `from_user`, not two. The field's related name is `from_user`, so you're specifying that in the query. And make sure that you're comparing a user object to the `from_user` field, or an email string to `from_user__email`.

Comment: Yeh spotted that mistake. Thanks seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

users = UserRoleAccount.objects.filter(groups__in = ura_groups).distinct().exclude(id=ura.id)